# Line break rendering of the first paragraph of a question in mousever on the main page

Tags: bug, design, homepage, linebreak

The
first
words
of
a
question
are
displayed
in
the
mouseover
when
hovering
over
the 
question
on
the
main
page.

It seems that single line breaks in the markdown will be rendered as line breaks, although when opening the question itself, only double line breaks will render as a new paragraph.

In this question, I have added line breaks between each word of the first sentence. Note that the first sentence is displayed on a single line. However the mouseover text on the frontpage looks a little different, showing all the line breaks:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I am curious if this is by design or a bug. It would allow some better control of how the preview is rendered, but it may lead to unintended consequences when this behaviour is not known.

Comment: I don't get that hover box. What OS / browser?

Comment: I tested this on Windows 7 with Firefox, Chrome and IE, all show the popup. It only appears on the frontpage tough, not on the "newest questions" page, or a search page

Comment: Yep, reproduced in Google Chrome on Ubuntu (latest, 14.04.2 respectively), although I only see 10 lines then `...`